# Out of bounds. Trying to access index 98 for no apparent reason

Tags: java, arrays, import, indexoutofboundsexception

As a challenge to my beginner programming ability I thought it would be fun to see if I could code a simple brute force password thing. So I've started writing an application which generates, given a value for the length of the string, every alphanumeric permutation it could take. However, as I am a complete programming newbie I am having troubles.

Firstly, despite having imported java.lang.Math, I'm getting errors saying cannot find symbol: pow. I managed to fix this by writing out in full java.lang.Math.pow(); when I use the function instead, but why that works but import does not is beyond me.

Secondly, regardless of the length input, after inputting I get the runtime error:

```
aaException in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 98
at combination.main(combination.java:53)
```

Which suggests that in line 53:

```
current[j] = alphanum[((int)current[j])+1];
```

I'm apparently trying to access index 98 in either current[] or alphanum[]?
Which as far as I can see shouldn't be happening...

I'm fairly stumped by this development. Anyway, here's my code:

```
//48-57 65-90 97-122

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class combination {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Alphanum will be an array of chars: the lowercase letters of the alphabet, the uppercase, and the numbers 0-9.
        char[] alphanum = new char[62];

        //Set indexes 0-25 as lowercase a-z, and indexes 26-51 as uppercase A-Z, using ascii conversion.
        for (int i=0; i<26; i++) {
            alphanum[i] = (char)(i+97);
            alphanum[i+26] = (char)(i+65);
        }

        //Set indexes 51-61 as 0-9.
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            alphanum[i+52] = (char)(i+48);
        }

        //Take in variable for length.
        System.out.print("Enter length: ");
        int length = in.nextInt();

        //Current will be an array of chars: it will hold the current permutation being generated.
        char[] current = new char[length];

        //Set all indexes in current to "a" by default, and print this string as the first permutation.
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            current[i] = alphanum[0];
            System.out.print(current[i]);
        }

        //power will be a temporary double, used to calculate the number of iterations needed, as the pow function works with doubles.
        double power = (java.lang.Math.pow(62.00, ((double)length)));

        //Convert power to an integer, iterations, and subtract 1 because one iteration was already printed previously.
        int iterations = ((int)power)-1;

        /*The loop works like this. The rightmost char is checked, and if it is the maximum value of the idex
        it is reverted to idex 0 again and the index value of the char to the left of it is increased by 1,
        if it is not the maximum then it is just increased by 1. This is iterated the right number of times such
        that every alphanumeric permutation of that length has been returned.*/
        for (int i=0; i<iterations; i++) {
            for (int j=(length-1); j>=0; j--) {
                if ((j!=0) && (((int)current[j])==122)) {
                    current[j] = alphanum[0];
                    current[j-1] = alphanum[((int)current[j-1])+1];
                } else if (j!=0) {
                    current[j] = alphanum[((int)current[j])+1];
                } else {
                    System.out.println("This has looped too many times. Something is wrong.");
                }
            }

            //At the end of each iteration, print the string.
            for (int l=0; l<length; l++) {
                System.out.print(current[l]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd be really thankful for any help or insight you could offer. ^_^

Comment: The error with pow is (I guess) because it is a static function, you must use Math.pow(x,y) or import static java.lang.Math

Comment: Why don't you debug the problem?

Comment: @Thomas I'm just using notepad++ and the command line javac to write and compile. Does notepad++ have that functionality for java?

Comment: Apprently not, but you can add System.out.println() to your code and debug by printing variable values to console.

Comment: Totally agree. How can anybody expect to program if you can't do simple debugging like using System.out.println() to see the value of the variables in question. Basic debugging is the first skill you need to learn.

Comment: camickr, he already said he is a total newbie, so tell him how to do so. Your comment is not helpful at all

Comment: @Miquel, he knows how to use System.out.println(), since the program already does so. I suggested be print out the values of the variables in question.

Comment: Thanks for defending me Miquel, but he's right, and what they said was helpful. I never thought to do that. I'll do that next time and solve my problem with much less hassle. Thanks for the tip Thomas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `alphanum` array has size 62, and the meaning of `((int)current[j-1])+1` is 98 (> 62).

The int value of char 'a' is 97.

Comment: Ah! Yes. I see where I am going wrong now. Silly mistake. Thank you.

Comment: There are no clever mistakes. But even the cleverest man makes them. It's our nature.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm apparently trying to access index 98 in either current[] or
>   alphanum[]? Which as far as I can see shouldn't be happening...

This is perfectly possible since you try to access an element in alphanum at a certain index, where the index is derived from the contents of your current array. I suggest you print out the contents of those arrays at different steps and you will quickly discover where exactly your code behaves not as you thought it would

```
current[j] = alphanum[((int)current[j])+1];
```

Here you try to access

```
int index = ((int)current[j])+1;
current[j] = alphanum[index];
```

where index seems to be 98